# MySQL Email Filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, email, filter

Hey guys I'm stuck trying to figure out the code to this question on MySQL as an HR

The company email naming standard is to concatenate the first character of the first name with
the last name (for example SKING for Steven King) Write a select statement that returns the
employee ID, first name, last name and email of the employees whose email does not follow
the company standard

`SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, Last_Name, EMAIL FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMAIL NOT SUBSTRING(FIRST_NAME, 1);`

I get an error of: Incorrect syntax near 'SUBSTRING'.

Thanks for anyone helping me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above query is giving an error because Substring needs one more parameter as:

```
SUBSTRING(FIRST_NAME,1,1);
```

But i think above query will not even give the right answer because it will just check first character of First name in the email not the lastname as well. I hope below given query might help.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, Last_Name, EMAIL FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMAIL NOT Like ''+LEFT(FIRST_NAME,1) + Last_Name +'%'
```

Comment: Yep! That's the right one.  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah i think so!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the 3rd parameter to SUBSTRING(string, starting_position, num_of_characters)? Since you are only wanting the first character to match?

```
SUBSTRING(FIRST_NAME,1,1);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, Last_Name, EMAIL
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE EMAIL <> CONCAT(SUBSTRING(FIRST_NAME,1,1), Last_Name, '@domain.com')
```

Comment: Yes! That's just what I'm looking for. Thank you for your speedy response!

Comment: The output should be as follows although, I'm only looking for emails that do not match the email standards and not editing them.
https://gyazo.com/d1807c176fec77ff25d01a9a368564de

Comment: I believe that is why it reads "EMAIL <> ..." Did you make sure to update the "@domain.com" to the actual domain used in the emails?

Comment: Missed out on that one, thanks for pointing it out ^_^

Comment: I think the biggest difference in my answer and @Nouman_0x45 is that his will have a possibility to capture a few more instances. For example, if "John Smith" email is "jsmith@example.com" or "jsmith123@example.com" his will still count it as a match. So if you want that, then his is the way to go. If you want it to be exact, then mine would probably solve it better.